# strdup each line into the char ** (array)

Tags: c, arrays, alsa

I wont to strdup each line into the char **result. I did the following:

```
static char **alsa_get_device(void)
{
    int o;
    char **result;

    o = 0;
    for (elem = snd_mixer_first_elem(handle); elem; elem = snd_mixer_elem_next(elem)) {
        if (!snd_mixer_selem_is_active(elem))
            continue;
        if (!snd_mixer_selem_has_playback_volume(elem))
            continue;
        result[o] = strdup(snd_mixer_selem_get_name(elem));
        o++;

        result[o] = NULL;
    }

    return result;
}
```

and make function to return GList:

```
GList *get_mixer_list(void)
{
    int i;
    char **array, *dev;
    GList *result = NULL;

    array = alsa_get_device();
    if (!array)
        return NULL;

    i = 0;  
    dev = array[i];
    while (dev) {
        char *text = g_strdup(dev);
        result = g_list_append(result, text);
        free(dev);
        dev = array[++i];
    }           
    free(array);

    return result;
}
```

but this crash when I use: result[o] = strdup(snd_mixer_selem_get_name(elem));

Comment: What is `elem`? And `result` is used uninitialized.

Comment: You never allocated the space for `result` — you're using it uninitialized.  That's bad news.

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler...

Answer (score 0):

well here are the things that are wrong in your code :

- as said in the comment `result` is used uninitialized
- you used `free(array)` without using `malloc()`
- in this segment :

  ```
  char *text = g_strdup(dev);
  result = g_list_append(result, text);
  free(dev);
  dev = array[++i];
  ```

you should replace `free(dev)` with `free(text)`